# use _trackXXX columns in the business object model

Tags: codefluent

Is there any way to view the persistence tracking fields (_trackLastWriteTime) as properties in my BOM.
I've seen a similar question in your website forums, but due to the updates you made to it, answers are lacking of "code" sections, so they are useless.
Thanks again!
Josep.

Comment: I will reach the support about the missing source code... It was online few weeks ago. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The Knowledge Center has been fixed : http://www.softfluent.com/product/codefluent-entities/knowledge-center/use-_trackxxx-columns-in-the-buisness-object-model

Comment: Thanks for your quick fixing! It's a good place for first search for FAQ search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare the following properties to the entity:

```
<cf:property name="LastWriteTime" typeName="datetime" persistenceName="_trackLastWriteTime" readOnLoad="true" readOnSave="true" persistent="false"/>
<cf:property name="CreationTime" typeName="datetime" persistenceName="_trackCreationTime" readOnLoad="true" persistent="false" />
<cf:property name="CreationUser" persistenceName="_trackCreationUser" readOnLoad="true" persistent="false" />
<cf:property name="LastWriteUser" persistenceName="_trackLastWriteUser" readOnLoad="true" readOnSave="true" persistent="false" />
```

- **persistenceName** should match the column name. This is the default column name but it could be different in your context. The property name is not important, only the persistence/column name.
- **persistent = false** means the property is not persistent. This instructs the inference pipeline to not create a column corresponding to this property (because in fact it has already created that column).
- **readOnLoad = true** and/or **readOnSave = true** means all layers will load and/or save this property, although it's been marked as non persistent.

Comment: Just don't forget to add typeName="datetime" on Date/Time related properties or you'll get an exception when the instance is reading from the database at the persistence layer methods.